# Android Internet permission and Google Play filtering

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, uses-feature

**I want to know which filtering `android.permission.INTERNET` adds on Google Play, if it adds something.**

I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to my manifest in order to have access to Internet, but this is not a main function of my app. So, I don't want to get filtered in Google Play because of this. There is no matching `<uses-feature>` for this, so my question is what do I need to add with `required="false"` to avoid filtering.

I guess I could add

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
```

but what about mobile Internet (3G/4G), do I also need this?

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: do you think there is an android device out there which does not have internet access?

Comment: it's possible, i suppose. unlikely, but it's not a requirement for the device to run android.

Comment: Google Play doesn't filter based on requested permissions: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/filters.html

Comment: it doesn't, but some permissions have features attached to them that are used for filtering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The telephony feature refers to the ability to make phone calls. I think the Internet permission is enough. You can have devices with 3G but not telephony. Also, I don't think the store filters on permissions. Some permissions have IMPLIED feature requirements, but internet is not one of them. You can check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

Comment: This note is what confused me _"It's important to understand that the permissions that you request in <uses-permission> elements can directly affect how Google Play filters your application"_. However, I looked in [Permissions that Imply Feature Requirements](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions) and `INTERNET` is not there. So, I guess is not causing any filtering. Thanks!

Comment: the docs can't be trusted at the moment for how filtering happens.

Comment: they were always reliable for me